# How can we show $n \subset m \rightarrow n \in m \lor n=m$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to prove that for any natural numbers $n,m$ it holds that:

$$n \subset m \leftrightarrow n \in m \lor n=m$$

$"\Leftarrow"$: If $n \in m \lor n=m$, using the sentence: *For any natural numbers $m,n$ it holds that $n \in m \rightarrow n \subset m$*, we conclude that $n \subset m$.

$"\Rightarrow"$:Could we  justify it like that?

$$n \subset m \rightarrow n=m \lor n \subsetneq m$$

When $n=m$, the desired property is satisfied.

When $n \subsetneq m$ How could we show that $n=m \lor n \subsetneq m$ ? Could we show it using induction? If so, how could we do this?

Comment: Careful here! $m\subset m$ but $\{m\}\notin m$. You mean $n\subsetneq m \to \{n\}\in m$

Comment: @AlexR How else could we show the implication?

Comment: You're on the right track. Make a trivial case $n=m$ and a nontrivial case $n\subsetneq m$ ;)

Comment: @AlexR So, could we say it like that?

$$n \subset m \leftrightarrow n=m \lor \{ n \} \in m$$

Can we conclude from $n \in \{ n \} \wedge \{ n \} \in m$ that $n \in m$ ?

Comment: No we can't but we can conclude from $\{n\}\in m$ that $n\in m$ by construction of $m$.

Comment: @AlexR Could you explain me further how we could justify it?

Comment: It follows inductively from the successor function $S(n) = \{n, \{n\}\}$

Comment: @AlexR How could we use this set?

Comment: Hang on I'll write it up.

Answer (score 1):

**Proposition 1**: $\{n\} \in m \to n \in m$
*Proof*: For $m=\emptyset$ we are okay since there is no $\{n\}\in m$.
Now let $\{n\}\in m \to n\in m$. We must show that $\{n\}\in S(m) \to n\in S(m)$.
$$S(m) = m\cup \{m\}$$
Thus $\{n\} \in S(m) \to \{n\}\in m \vee \{n\} = \{m\}$. In the first case we have by condition $n\in m$ and since $m\subset S(m)$, $n\in S(m)$. The second case $\{n\} = \{m\} \to n=m \to n\in S(m)$, thus $n\in S(m)$.
$\qquad\Box$

**Proposition 2**: $n\subset m \to n \in m \vee n = m$
*Proof*: If $n=m$ then clearly $n\subset m$, now assume $n\subset m$ and $n\ne m$, i.e. $n\subsetneq m$. Now if $n\subsetneq m$ then $\{n\}\in m$ as you said. Finally by Proposition 1, $n\in m$.

Alternative last step without Proposition 1: Since $n\subsetneq m$, $n \cup \{n\} = S(n) \subset m$ so especially $n\in S(n)\subset m$, i.e. $n\in m$ as claimed.

Comment: Alex R Couldn't we also justify it like that:

$$n \subset m \leftrightarrow n=m \lor n \subsetneq m$$

When $n=m$, the desired property is satisfied.

When $n \subsetneq m$, then $\{ n \} \in m \rightarrow \{ n \} \subset m \rightarrow n \in m$.

Or am I wrong?

Comment: @evinda That's what I did but with reasoning _why_ those $\to$ hold.

Comment: Do these $\rightarrow$ have to be proven, or are they known?

Comment: @evinda The $\{n\} \in m \to \{n\} \subset m$ is nontrivial. It's exactly my proposition 1.

Comment: Couldn't we also justify it, using the following sentence?

$$\text{ For any natural numbers } m,n \text{ it holds that :} \\ n \in m \rightarrow n \subset m$$

Comment: @evinda No, because $\{n\}$ is not a natural number.

Comment: Alex R A ok.. But is considering the set $S(m)$ the only way to prove it?

Comment: @evinda I am positive about that because in $S$ lies the specific form of the natural numbers.

Comment: I think $S(n):=n\cup\{n\}$.

Comment: @Nishant Thank you, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

**Lemma 1**: Every natural number is a transitive set.

Proof: Induction. $0=\varnothing$, so it's trivially transitive. Assume $n$ is transitive. Then $S(n)=n\cup\{n\}$ is transitive: let $k\in m\in S(n)$. Then either $m\in n$ or $m=n$. If $m\in n$, then since $n$ is transitive, $k\in n\subsetneq S(n)$, so $k\in S(n)$. Otherwise, $m=n$, in which case $k\in n$ directly, and thus $k\in S(n)$. By induction, every natural number is transitive.

Note: Being transitive is equivalent to all elements also being subsets.

**Lemma 2**: No natural number is an element of itself.

Proof: Induction. $0=\varnothing$ and $\varnothing\notin\varnothing$. Now assume $n\notin n$. $S(n)=n\cup\{n\}$. If $S(n)\in S(n)$, then either $S(n)=n$ or $S(n)\in n$. If $S(n)=n$, then $\{n\}\subseteq n\implies n\in n$, contradicting the inductive hypothesis. If $S(n)\in n$, then since $n\in S(n)$, and since $n$ is transitive, we have $n\in n$, again contradicting the inductive hypothesis. Thus, no natural number is an element of itself.

**Lemma 3**: $\omega$ is totally ordered by $\in$.

Proof: By Lemma 1, $\in$ gives a transitive relation on $\omega$. By Lemma 2, this relation is irreflexive. Thus, we need only show that for any $n, m\in\omega$, at least one of $m\in n, m=n, n\in m$ is true (transitivity and irreflexivity prevent more than one from being true). We fix $m$ and induct on $n$. Firstly, $0\in m$ or $0=m$. Next, if $n\in m$, then $S(n)\in m$ or $(n)=m$. If $n=m$, then $m\in S(n)$. Finally, if $m\in n$, then $m\in n\in S(n)\implies m\in S(n)$, since $S(n)$ is transitive. Thus, $m$ is comparable to any natural number. Since $m$ was arbitrary, any two natural numbers are comparable, so $\omega$ is totally ordered by $\in$.

**Theorem**: If $n, m\in \omega$, then $n\subsetneq m\implies n\in m$.

Assume $n\subsetneq m$. We seek to show that $n\in m$. Since $\omega$ is totally ordered by elementhood, we have either $n\in m$ or $m\in n$. If $m\in n$, then since $n$ is transitive, all elements of $n$, including $m$, are subsets, so $n\subsetneq m\subseteq n\implies n\subsetneq n$, a contradiction.

Comment: This is more elegant, I think (+1).